# Remove Aptana Studio 3 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have actually two questions.

1. I was using Eclipse in ubuntu 12.04LTS, it was working fine. Then I install Aptana   Studio 3 and after installing Aptana Studio 3 Eclipse stop working. Any thoughts about this  ?
2. I install Aptana Studio 3 in /opt/Aptana_Studio_3. How can I remove Aptana Studio 3 so I can install again Eclipse, actually I want to switch back to Eclipse.

Comment: Ia this Aptana stuff from Ubuntu's own repositories or from somewhere else? Installed how? --- In any case, you'll probaby have to install eclipse again if it got damaged somehow. Be sure to remove any configuration in your account that might be left over.

Comment: No, Its not a stuff from Ubuntu repositories. I first download .zip file from its website http://www.aptana.com/ and then extracted to /opt/Aptana_Studio_3 directory

Comment: Then it should be a simple matter of deleting it from there. But I can't see how it breaks eclipse for you. Did it do some configuration in your account? Did the installation request changing system-wide or account configuration (edit files, ...)? What exactly does "eclipse is broken" mean?

Comment: Actually Aptana is based on Eclipse before installing Aptana as a pre request I had to install this package     sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk libjpeg62 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 git-core  
I followed these instructions to install Aptana. 
http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/

Comment: those look inocuous (Java, JPEG, web, and git). That could screw up your eclipse if it meant removing stuff on which Eclipse depends, but I doubt apt would have you let you do that without any warning. Is Eclipse still installed (it might have get erased by the above)?

Comment: No this was not erased Eclipse, but as it was not working so later on I uninstall and install again but is not working.